# Windows Phone 7 Webbrowser Search pattern

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, browser

Hi i'm creating an application, I have two separate pages one main and a Web Browser page.

What i have on the main page is a textBlock and a button and on the Web Browser i only have the Web Browser Control.

What i need to do is that if the user writes for example chocolate or anything else in the textblock it should somehow be transferred to the webbrowser Control and search on chocolate there automatically when you press the button on the main page.

I need some help knowing what to write here so any help would be appreciated.

For the web browser i have written the following code please tell suggestions of improvements if you have:

```
webBrowser1.source = (new Uri("http://bing.com/" , Urikind.Absolute));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see each search engine pattern here

```
"Google", URLPattern = "http://www.google.com/search?q={0}"
"Yahoo", URLPattern = "http://search.yahoo.com/search?p={0}"
"Bing", URLPattern = "http://www.bing.com/search?q={0}"
```

Just replace your text with it:
**for example:**

```
String url = String.Format(URLPattern, textblock.Text);
webBrowser1.source = (new Uri(string.Format(url) , Urikind.Absolute));
```

Comment: I have done as you did yet the only problem now occurring is that it cannot find the searchfield(textblock which is on the mainpage) it gives the error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property.                                                                                                                               String url = String.Format("http://www.bing.com/search?q{0}", MainPage.SearchField.Text);                                webBrowser1.Source = (new Uri(string.Format(url), UriKind.Absolute));

Comment: is you're web browser in second page and text block in mainpage?

Comment: yes i have 2 pages the first with the button and the searchfield, the second with only the webbrowser.

Comment: before create new instance of second page send textblock content to second page as a variable.u are now calling MainPage.SearchField.Text that is static.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help, though how do i write it then? im very new and is learning C# for the first time.

Comment: i think you are make new instance of sec page,create for example a public string variable,and after make new instance of sec page initiate it with text block text and in sec page:String url = String.Format(URLPattern, yorvariable);
webBrowser1.source = (new Uri(string.Format(url) , Urikind.Absolute));

Comment: Hmm unsure how to do that but i post the code for the both pages its not really much for those two pages. its a bigger project and the webbrowser is a function to use in the application.

Comment: namespace Secret
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage                                          private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/WebBrowser.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
 private void SearchField_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}

Comment: Webbrowser Page:                                                                 namespace Secret
{
    public partial class WebBrowser : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public WebBrowser()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void webBrowser1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            String url = String.Format("http://www.bing.com/search?q{0}", MainPage.SearchField.Text);

            webBrowser1.Source = (new Uri(string.Format(url), UriKind.Absolute));


            }
        }
    }              @irsog

Comment: okey i have fixed the searchfield so it finds it now. the problem im having now is that its not searching on bing for the content written in the searchfield. do i have to move the whole code for the button procedure instead?